# How can I define intercept-url dynamically using Database that load them in runtime not just when start web application?

Tags: java, spring, security, web-applications, spring-security

I've been working on a spring security recently and I know how I can define intercept-url (in Spring Security) dynamically using a Database.

but i need restart my web application to load defined intercept-url from database. But i need to load when i add a new intercept-url to database.

```
@Component
public class FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean instanceof FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource) {
            return metadataSource;
        }
        if(bean instanceof FilterChainProxy.FilterChainValidator) {
            return new FilterChainProxy.FilterChainValidator() {
                @Override
                public void validate(FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy) {

                }
           };
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;


    }
}
```

---

```
@Component("filterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource")
public class FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource, InitializingBean{
    private FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource delegate;
    private RequestConfigMappingService requestConfigMappingService;
    private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> expressionHandler;

    @Autowired
    public FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource(CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler,
        RequestConfigMappingService filterInvocationService) {
        this.expressionHandler = expressionHandler;
        this.requestConfigMappingService = filterInvocationService;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return this.delegate.getAllConfigAttributes();
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        return this.delegate.getAttributes(object);
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return this.delegate.supports(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        List<RequestConfigMapping> requestConfigMappings = requestConfigMappingService.getRequestConfigMappings();
        LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> requestMap = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>(requestConfigMappings.size());
        for(RequestConfigMapping requestConfigMapping : requestConfigMappings) {
            RequestMatcher matcher = requestConfigMapping.getMatcher();
            requestMap.put(matcher,requestConfigMapping.getAttributes());
        }
        this.delegate = new ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(requestMap, expressionHandler);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Repository("requestConfigMappingService")
public class JdbcRequestConfigMappingService implements RequestConfigMappingService {


    private SecurityFilterMetaDataService securityFilterMetaDataService;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcRequestConfigMappingService(SecurityFilterMetaDataService securityFilterMetaDataService) {
        if (securityFilterMetaDataService == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("securityFilterMetaDataService cannot be null");
        }
        this.securityFilterMetaDataService = securityFilterMetaDataService;
    }

    @Override
    public List<RequestConfigMapping> getRequestConfigMappings() {
        String pattern = "";
        String expressionString = "";
        List<SecurityFilterMetaData> securityFilterMetaDataList = securityFilterMetaDataService.getByAscOrder("sortOrder");
        List<RequestConfigMapping> requestConfigMappings = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SecurityFilterMetaData securityFilterMetaData : securityFilterMetaDataList) {
            pattern = securityFilterMetaData.getAntPattern();
            expressionString = securityFilterMetaData.getExpression();
            AntPathRequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(pattern);
            requestConfigMappings.add(new RequestConfigMapping(matcher, new SecurityConfig(expressionString)));
        }
        return requestConfigMappings;


    }

    private static final class RequestConfigMappingMapper implements RowMapper<RequestConfigMapping> {
        @Override
        public RequestConfigMapping mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            String pattern = rs.getString("ant_pattern");
            String expressionString = rs.getString("expression");
            AntPathRequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(pattern);
            return new RequestConfigMapping(matcher, new SecurityConfig(expressionString));
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
public interface RequestConfigMappingService {

    List<RequestConfigMapping> getRequestConfigMappings();

}
```

---

```
public final class RequestConfigMapping {
    private final RequestMatcher matcher;
    private final Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes;

    public RequestConfigMapping(RequestMatcher matcher, ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        this(matcher, Collections.singleton(attribute));
    }

     public RequestConfigMapping(RequestMatcher matcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        if (matcher == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("matcher cannot be null");
        }
        Assert.notEmpty(attributes, "attributes cannot be null or emtpy");

        this.matcher = matcher;
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public RequestMatcher getMatcher() {
        return matcher;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At last I found answer. FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource  must change.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that getAttributes will be invoked for every request that Spring Security intercepts so you will most likely want some sort of caching.

```
@Component("filterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource")
public class FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource, InitializingBean{
    private FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource delegate;
    private RequestConfigMappingService requestConfigMappingService;
    private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> expressionHandler;

    @Autowired
    public FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource(CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler,
    RequestConfigMappingService filterInvocationService) {
        this.expressionHandler = expressionHandler;
        this.requestConfigMappingService = filterInvocationService;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return this.delegate.getAllConfigAttributes();
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        List<RequestConfigMapping> requestConfigMappings = requestConfigMappingService.getRequestConfigMappings();
        LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> requestMap = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>(requestConfigMappings.size());
        for(RequestConfigMapping requestConfigMapping : requestConfigMappings) {
            RequestMatcher matcher = requestConfigMapping.getMatcher();
            requestMap.put(matcher,requestConfigMapping.getAttributes());
        }
        this.delegate = new ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(requestMap, expressionHandler);
        return this.delegate.getAttributes(object);
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return this.delegate.supports(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        List<RequestConfigMapping> requestConfigMappings = requestConfigMappingService.getRequestConfigMappings();
        LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> requestMap = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>(requestConfigMappings.size());
        for(RequestConfigMapping requestConfigMapping : requestConfigMappings) {
            RequestMatcher matcher = requestConfigMapping.getMatcher();
            requestMap.put(matcher,requestConfigMapping.getAttributes());
        }
        this.delegate = new ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(requestMap, expressionHandler);
    }
}
```